# Java: IOException when writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, exception, ioexception, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

Since `ByteArrayOutputStream` simply writes to memory, an `IOException` should never occur. However, because of the contract of the `OutputStream` interface, all stream operations define `IOException` in their `throws` clause.

What is the correct way to "handle" this never-occurring `IOException`? Simply wrap operations in an empty `try-catch` block?

Or are there any actual situations where `ByteArrayOutputStream` could throw an exception?

(See also: [How can I handle an IOException which I know can never be thrown, in a safe and readable manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045829/how-can-i-handle-an-ioexception-which-i-know-can-never-be-thrown-in-a-safe-and-r))

**EDIT**

As Jon points out, `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't declare a `throws` clause on the `write` methods it defines -- however, it inherits `write(byte[])` from `OutputStream`, and that one does throw `IOEXception` (quite odd that `BAOS` wouldn't override this method, as it could replace the superclass version -- which writes one byte at a time -- with a far more efficient `arraycopy` call)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `ByteArrayOutputStream` *doesn't* declare that any of its methods throw `IOException` except `writeTo` and `close`. (I don't know why `close` still declares it, to be honest.)

If you've got a reference of type `OutputStream` though, you would still see the throws declarations from that, of course.

I wouldn't use an empty catch block - I'd throw something like `IllegalStateException` or a similar unchecked exception: it means you're in a situation you *really* don't expect, and something's gone badly wrong.

Comment: the IOException on `close()` must be a mistake - especially when the javadoc says it "has no effect"

Comment: +1 Thanks! I just noticed that `ByteArrayOutputStream.write` doesn't in fact declare `IOException` -- but Eclipse complains about an unhandled exception whenever I use it... strange.

Comment: @Jen: Are you sure you're calling methods on a variable *declared* as `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: @irreputable: That's no mistake. Just because `InputStream` does nothing doesn't mean concrete subclasses do nothing. They might flush before releasing the stream (and a lot of them do). `InputStream` declares the contract and this contract allows for errors on closing a stream.

Comment: @Jon: I'm calling `write(byte[])` from within a subclass of `ByteArrayOutputStream`. `BAOS` does not override this method, so I'm actually the method defined in `OutputStream` (which does throw an `IOE`)

Comment: @Jen: Ah, right. That makes sense. You could always just call `write(data, 0, data.length)` yourself.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, that's the best approach -- really strange that `write(byte[])` isn't overridden...

Comment: @Jen: Well, the override wouldn't actually have any different code - it would have the same code as the base class, just without the exception declaration. It's a bit of an odd case :)

Comment: @Jon: True... it would duplicate the call to `write(byte[],int,int)`, but at least it would keep the API consistent (throwing vs. not throwing)

Comment: @musiKk see javadoc on ByteArrayOutputStream.close()

Comment: @irreputable: Ah. My comment referred to `InputStream`. The exception on `close` in `ByteArrayOutputStream` is indeed queer.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 11, there is also a [new method](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180410) `ByteArrayOutputStream.writeBytes(byte[])` which does not throw an `IOException` as well:

```
/**
 * Writes the complete contents of the specified byte array
 * to this {@code ByteArrayOutputStream}.
 *
 * ...
 *
 * @since   11
 */
public void writeBytes(byte b[]) {
    write(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

You could use this method if you don't want to handle an `IOException` which is never thrown.

Comment: I could see in Java 8 a method `write(byte b[], int off, int len)` which is [what the newly introduced syntax also makes a call to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575480/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bytearrayoutputstream/51789541#51789541).. Point being, the existing method also [didn't throw an IOException as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50739082/1746118)

Answer (score 2):

> I just noticed that ByteArrayOutputStream.write doesn't in fact declare IOException -- but Eclipse complains about an unhandled exception whenever I use it... strange.

That's easy to explain.  You've probably done something like this:

```
    OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ...
    os.write();
```

The "problem" is that you are calling the method as `OutputStream.write()` rather than as `ByteArrayOutputStream.write()`.  So the compiler says:

> "Ah ... `write()` on an `OutputStream` can throw an `IOException`, so you gotta deal with it."

It cannot say:

> "This particular `OutputStream` is really a `ByteArrayOutputStream` ... so we'll let you off."

because the JLS doesn't allow it.

This is one of those edge cases where following "best practice" by coding to the interface rather than the implementation class comes back to bite you.

<sup>OK so ...</sup>

- its a gentle nip, not a full-on bite.
- `OutputStream` is implemented as a Java class not a Java interface, but that is beside the point.
- most compilers don't actually hold conversations with you while compiling your code :-)

Comment: In general you're right. However `ByteArrayOutputStream` unintelligently redeclares `close()` doing nothing and throwing `IOException` so in this case the reference type doesn't matter (OpenJDK).

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. I found out what's going on. I'm calling `write(byte[])` from within a subclass of `ByteArrayOutputStream`. `BAOS` does not override this method, so I'm actually the method defined in `OutputStream` (which does throw an `IOE`)

Answer (score 1):

A typical cliche is to `throw new RuntimeException(theIOException)` in the catch block. If the impossible happens, you at least find out about it.

Answer (score 1):

Exception chaining is the best practice in this situation. i.e throw a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 1):

There is an enhancement [ticket](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787155) for this issue since 2002. The reason why this does not get fixed, is that it would impact compatibility with previous java versions.

Here follow 2 workarounds that I would consider.

## Workaround 1

**The `write(byte[], int, int)` method does not throw checked exceptions.** It is a bit more verbose to specify the 2 additional parameters. But all by all the footprint is smaller without the try-catch.

```
baos.write(array, 0, array.length);
```

## Workaround 2

Another possible solution, is to **write your own `ByteUtil` class**, which catches the exception internally.

```
public final class ByteUtil
{
  public static void write(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, byte[] bytes)
  {
    try
    {
      baos.write(bytes);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      // impossible
    }
  }
}

// usage
ByteUtil.write(baos, bytes);
```