# How to convert Byte array to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, byte, bytearrayoutputstream

I need to convert a byte array to ByteArrayOutputStream so that I can display it on screen.

Comment: A `ByteArrayOutputStream` is meant to *receive* data. Are you sure you don't mean a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: With JDK/11, you can now use the utility provided to [write the complete byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789541/1746118) directly.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = ....;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
baos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Method description:

> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display a ByteArrayOutputStream.  What I suspect you are trying to do is

```
byte[] bytes = ...
String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // or some other encoding.
// display text.
```

You can make ByteArrayOutputStream do something similar but this is not obvious, efficient or best practice (as you cannot control the encoding used)

Answer (score 0):

With [JDK/11](http://jdk.java.net/11/), you can make use of the `writeBytes(byte b[])` API which eventually calls the  `write(b, 0, b.length)` as suggested in the [answer by Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18575536/1746118).

```
/**
 * Writes the complete contents of the specified byte array
 * to this {@code ByteArrayOutputStream}.
 *
 * @apiNote
 * This method is equivalent to {@link #write(byte[],int,int)
 * write(b, 0, b.length)}.
 *
 * @param   b     the data.
 * @throws  NullPointerException if {@code b} is {@code null}.
 * @since   11
 */
public void writeBytes(byte b[]) {
    write(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

The sample code would simply transform into --

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
baos.writeBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: What's the difference between `writeBytes(byte[])` and `write(byte[])`?

Comment: It's inheritet from OutputStream