# Why did Java 11 add writeBytes​(byte[] b) method to the ByteArrayOutputStream class while the write​(byte[] b) method did the same?

Tags: java, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

Oracle added `writeBytes​(byte[] b)` method to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` class since Java 11. This method takes a byte array and writes it to `ByteArrayOutputStream`. However, `ByteArrayOutputStream` extends `OutputStream` class that defines a `write​(byte[] b)` to do same thing. Why did Java need a new method to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52308828/61158

Answer (score 6):

As noted by others, the benefit of the new method is that it isn't declared as `throws IOException`.

It was added in response to this issue [JDK-8180410 "ByteArrayOutputStream should not throw IOExceptions"](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8180410).  The stated rationale in the issue is simply that it makes no sense<sup>1</sup> to have to write a `try ... catch` for an exception that will never be thrown.  That's it.

They (strictly) didn't need to add it.  They added it as a convenience.

---

<sup>1 - As the reporter puts it: *"It's contradictive."*</sup>

Comment: Still entirely pointless AFAICS. If you know you have a `ByteArrayOutputStream` you know you can call `write()` without a `catch`, and so does the compiler, and if you don't know it you can't call `writeBytes()` anyway.

Comment: No, you cannot call `write` without caching `IOException`, because `IOException` is a checked Exception, which must be handled. One  could change the signature not to throw it, but that would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: @DorianGray - To be clear .... who was your comment addressed to?

Comment: @user207421 it was addressed to.

Answer (score 1):

[ByteArrayOutputStream.writeBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeBytes(byte%5B%5D)) doesn't throw the unnecessary `IOException`.

It's a new method specific to the byte array output stream, whereas the other options are inherited from [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html) and are declared to throw the checked `IOException` (which is an unnecessary pain to handle if you know you're writing to a byte array output stream - you don't have a network connection to fail or similar)

Comment: But what is the point? You can only call it if your reference variable is of type `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and if it is you can alreay call `write()` without a `catch`.

Comment: Which write() ? You either have to call a variant which throws a checked exception, or you have to provide the offset and length. writeBytes() mitigates both those issues